# SL4J configuration change or regex to mask email(recognized by '@' and '.com' ) in a Json

Tags: java, json, regex, string, slf4j

I want to mask email address in Java from a JSON while logging as a part of security protocols.
I have tried the primitive method of replacing using the string operations and it's not possible for me to search through the complete project.
Is there any possible configuration in SL4J or regex is the only way out

**If the below is the response printed by the log(slf4j):**

```
{
  "any_key": {

    "salt": "salt_here",
    "sel": "sel_here",
    "rules": [
      {
        "variation": 0,
        "clauses": [
          {
            "attribute": "email",
            "op": "in",
            "values": [
              "jack.jones@gmail.com",
              "david.beckham@yahoo.com"
            ],
            "negate": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**It should print the json in log as below:**

```
{
    "any_key": {
    "salt": "salt_here",
    "sel": "sel_here",
    "rules": [
      {
        "variation": 0,
        "clauses": [
          {
            "attribute": "email",
            "op": "in",
            "values": [
              "jac*******@******com",
              "dav**********@******com"
            ],
            "negate": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it programatically as below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String a[]){
    String result =mask("{\"id\":\"jack.sparrow@pirate.com\"}"); 

    System.out.println(result);

    }
    final static char ASTERICK = '*';
    final static char DOT = '.';
    final static char QUOTATION_MARK = '"';
    final static char ATMARK = '@';


    public static String mask(String jsonString) {
        try {
            if(false)
                return maskEmail(jsonString);

            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(@))").matcher(jsonString);
            List<Integer> positionList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while (m.find()) {
                positionList.add(m.start());
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < positionList.size(); index++) {
                String semiFinalString = maskEmailbeforeAtmark(jsonString,
                        positionList.get(index),ASTERICK);
                String finalString = maskEmailAfterAtmark(semiFinalString,
                        positionList.get(index),ASTERICK);
                jsonString = new String(finalString);
            }
            return jsonString;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return jsonString;
        }
    }



    /**
     * This method will stark masking before the Atmark(`@`) identifier.
     *
     * @param str
     * @return masked json String.
     * 
     */
    private static String maskEmailbeforeAtmark(String str, int index,char replacementCharacter) throws Exception{
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(str);
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        loop: for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            if (chars[i] == QUOTATION_MARK) {
                buff.replace(i+1, i + 2, Character.toString(chars[i + 1]));
                buff.replace(i + 2, i + 3, Character.toString(chars[i + 2]));
                buff.replace(i + 3, i + 4, Character.toString(chars[i + 3]));

                break loop;
            } else {
                buff.replace(i, i + 1, Character.toString(replacementCharacter));
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }

    /**
     * This method will stark masking after the Atmark(`@`) identifier.
     *
     * @param str
     * @return masked json String.
     * 
     */
    private static String maskEmailAfterAtmark(String str, int index,char replacementCharacter) throws Exception{
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(str);
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        loop: for (int i = index + 1; i <= str.length(); i++) {
            if (chars[i] == DOT)
                break loop;
            else
                buff.replace(i, i + 1, Character.toString(replacementCharacter));
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }

    /**
     * This method mask a part of the email string.
     *
     * @param email
     * @return number
     * 
     */

    private static boolean isJSONValid(String target) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(target);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            try {
                new JSONArray(target);
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static String maskEmail(String email) throws Exception {

            int start = 0;
            int end = email.length();
            if (start > end)
                return email;

            String semiMaskedString = maskEmailbeforeAtmark("\""+email,email.indexOf(ATMARK)+1,ASTERICK);
            String editedString= semiMaskedString.substring(1, semiMaskedString.length());
            String finalString = maskEmailAfterAtmark(editedString,editedString.indexOf(ATMARK),ASTERICK);
            return finalString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[\"|\']\p{L}{3}).*\@.*(?=com)
```

This regex will detect anything between `\"\p{L}{3}` (" followed by three letters) and `com`. You can then iterate the match and replace every character with `*` (except for @).

**Edit:**

To include 'something@xyz.com' (`som******@****com`) use the updated regex now allowing `\"` and `\'` as delimiters.

https://regex101.com/r/qX1MjR/2

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. 
Above answer is skipping one case where i want the answer like 
'bhu*******`@`******com'

Comment: Can you post the full case?

Comment: It’s same as above.

Comment: import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        String str = "{\"rules\":[{\"variation\":0,\"clauses\":[{\"values\":[\"jack.jones@gmail.com\",\"david.beckham@yahoo.com\"]}]}]}";
        Test mpr = new Test();
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=[\"|\']\\p{L}{3}).*\\@.*(?=com)", "*"));
    }
}

Comment: Maybe you should try to match every line of the code above. If it matches, use another Java-function to generate your output and replace the matching line with the generated one